# Homset vs one collection

Tags: ct.category-theory

There are 2 main ways to describe a category, either using homsets for each pair of objects or just a single collection of morphisms with the objects (i.e. a 2 sorted structure). The homset definition seems to be more in use, probably because most practical categories are constructed from defining the homset for each pair of objects and then taking the disjoint union.

The homset definition is also better suited for defining enriched categories (as remarked in ncat lab). One type of enriched category is the preadditive category (each homset is an abelian group).

I was wondering if it's possible to define a preadditive category using the one collection of morphisms method. For example, can we introduct 3 functions +, -, and 0, where + is a partial function on Mor(C)XMor(C)->Mor(C) defined on parallel arrows, - a function Mor(C)->Mor(C), and 0 a function Obj(C)XObj(C)-> Mor(C), and add axioms that says the usual abelian group properties, and that k(f+g)=kf+kg whenever the left side is defined (consequently the right will be as well).

Comment: Good question. A preadditive category is just a "partially defined ring".

Answer (score 2):

One way to start is to look at $Mor(C)$ as an abelian group object in $Set/(Obj(C)\times Obj(C))$. Then one gets an abelian group structure on each fibre of $(s,t):Mor(C) \to Obj(C)\times Obj(C)$, i.e. each hom-set. Then composition can be defined as a map in $Ab(Set/(Obj(C)\times Obj(C)))$, the category of abelian group objects over $Obj(C)\times Obj(C)$.

This description should work for $Set$ replaced by any finitely complete category $S$, so that one can have pre-additive category objects in $S$.

Comment: And after a weekend away, here is a belated comment: what I defined would be called by some an internal _ringoid_, following the pattern group -> groupoid, given by allowing the number of objects to increase from one to many.